# How can I change a video container without re-encoding or compressing the file?

Tags: video, conversion, avi, subtitles, matroska

When I ripped my Kill Bill DVD I used handbrake and put it into a single avi.  I realize that I didn't get the subtitles, so what I want to do is convert the AVI to MKV and put the subtitles in the mkv.  How do I go about doing this without losing any qualityI don't care about compressing or anything ju?  I don't care about compressing or anything, just want to change the container.

If handbrake can do it, I'd prefer to use that since I already have it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MKVtoolnix](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/) can help with this.  I believe someone else already suggested this package to you in [an answer to another question](https://superuser.com/questions/64741/how-to-soft-code-an-mkv-with-subtitles/64768#64768).  As a commenter on that answer mentions, it will repackage your AVI with no quality lost.

Basically, you just run the `mkvmerge` program.  Since AVI and SRT files are both supported, you should be able to run this and get a working MKV.

```
$ mkvmerge -o out.mkv input.avi input.srt
```

If you run into problems, you'll need to figure out the proper tweaks to the command -- it can do a lot of things, but it can't guess what you want from it.  The [documentation](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/docs.html) is a great place to start.

Comment: i just tested it to make sure... if your SRT file is in sync already, it *really is that easy*.

Comment: oh really?? i didn't know that program would also convert the avi, i thought it would only merge the subtitles! Thanks, nice to know I only need one software to do this! :-)

Comment: WOW, literally too easy! thanks again!  I just ended up using the GUI tool anyway

Comment: technically there's no "conversion", it just strips the AVI container format and __repackages__ the existing streams in an MKV container.