# DVD to MKV with multiple audio tracks and subtitles

Tags: video, dvd, matroska

I wish to back up DVDs to MKV files, keeping the video in its original MPEG-2 format so as not to lose any quality, often with multiple audio tracks (the original and any commentaries) and all subtitles available on the DVD.

What is the best way of doing this?

So far it seems Handbrake comes close but won't let me use MPEG-2. I *think* I can do it using DVD Shrink to rip the MPEG-2 file and individual audio and subtitle files, Haali Media Splitter to demux the video so it can then be read into mkvmerge and combined into the MKV.

Is this really the best way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to soft code an MKV with subtitles?](http://superuser.com/questions/64741/how-to-soft-code-an-mkv-with-subtitles)

Comment: I don't think so, the main point here is the keeping of MPEG-2, the need to not lose any quality.

Comment: DVD Shrink is probably the best first step. Have you looked at handbrake for the following steps to get the MKV?

Answer (score 0):

[MakeMKV](http://www.makemkv.com) is your one-click solution to convert video that you own into free and patents-unencumbered format that can be played everywhere.

Comment: awesome solution worked really well and was shockingly fast. I was expecting many hours but it did it in seconds.