# Shouldn't I be able to plug a DVD/Blu-ray HDMI OUT into an HDMI capture card and then be able to decode the video with my computer's software?

Tags: video, hdmi, dvd, video-capture

I have a [DeckLink Quad HDMI Recorder](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/decklink/techspecs/W-DLK-36)

I am trying to get video out of a set of DVDs and Blu-rays and I don't know why this isn't working so far.

I've installed the capture card, I've installed the software to detect devices and receive video, but nothing good is happening.

Comment: Nope, because capture devices wouldn't be licenced to decrypt HDCP as per the answer you have. The thing is you don't have to, you can use a program like [MakeMKV](https://superuser.com/questions/172500/dvd-to-mkv-with-multiple-audio-tracks-and-subtitles/354681#354681) to get the video straight from the source without having to decode and recapture/reencode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from the product page you've linked:

> **Copy Protection**
>
> HDMI input is unable to capture from copy protected HDMI sources. Always confirm copyright ownership before capture or distribution of content.

Your content is protected with [HDCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection) and this capture card is unable to capture it.