# How to include .ass subtitles in an .mkv container in bulk?

Tags: subtitles, matroska

I have a folder with many many .mkv and for each of these I have a .ass file of the same name in the same folder. Is there a way to include all .ass files in their proper .mkv file without using mkvtoolnix to do it by hand for every single file?

Comment: [As shown here](http://superuser.com/a/64768/50173) `mkvtoolnix` can be utilized via command line. Are you interested in a script to automate this? What's your operating system? Do you have any basic programming skills?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu or Windows 10, yes.

Comment: Indeed I could write a bash script then, so you have basically given an answer.

Comment: If you do so, please don't forget to post your script as answer so others may benefit from your work :)