# How to embed subtitiles in avi file

Tags: video, conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I hard code a movie with subtitles?](https://superuser.com/questions/63736/how-do-i-hard-code-a-movie-with-subtitles)

What is the best and easiest way to embed subtitles (sub,idx files) in avi movies. My DVD player doesn't read subtitles.

Comment: Dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/63736/how-do-i-hard-code-a-movie-with-subtitles

Answer (score 0):

[**AVIAddXSubs**](http://www.calcitapp.com/AVIAddXSubs.php).

> AVIAddXSubs is a simple to use,  free program to subtitle videos converting the original srt files you may have.

Meanwhile, [**VirtualDubMod**](http://www.afterdawn.com/software/video_software/video_tools/virtualdubmod.cfm) is [popularly used](http://forums.afterdawn.com/thread_view.cfm/733628).