# add subtitle to a movie

Tags: windows, video, embedded, flv, subtitles

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do I hard code a movie with subtitles?](https://superuser.com/questions/63736/how-do-i-hard-code-a-movie-with-subtitles)
>   [How to soft code an MKV with subtitles?](https://superuser.com/questions/64741/how-to-soft-code-an-mkv-with-subtitles)

Do you know a good (& free if is possible) software which allow me to embed a subtitle in a movie? My movie is a flv file type.

Comment: You asked this very same question in September 2009 and accepted an answer. If that didn't work for you unaccept the answer and edit the question to bring it back to the home page rather than ask the question again.

Comment: in September I was asking about how to build subtitles, and now I'm asking about how to embed them into a movie.

Comment: And no it is not a duplicate with that question at all. Thx for trying to close my question even if you didn't understand it

Comment: so, is this a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/64741/how-to-soft-code-an-mkv-with-subtitles or http://superuser.com/questions/63736/how-do-i-hard-code-a-movie-with-subtitles then?

Answer (score 1):

[Avidemux](http://avidemux.org/) is a good tool. And it is free.
See [this](http://avidemux.org/admForum/viewtopic.php?id=4300) for info about subtitles embedding