# merge srt files with avi files

Tags: windows, software-rec, avi, subtitles

how do I merge an srt file with an avi file.
Is there a software for windows that I could use to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean hard coding a movie with subtitles, then you should see this question: [How do I hard code a movie with subtitles?](https://superuser.com/questions/63736/how-do-i-hard-code-a-movie-with-subtitles)

Otherwise, just give the same name to the movie and the subtitle file (they should be in the same folder too), and the subtitles will automatically be loaded when you play the video. For example:

```
C:\Terminator2.avi  
C:\Terminator2.srt
```

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip#Compatibility
http://forums.afterdawn.com/thread_view.cfm/373886
http://www.moviecodec.com/subtitles/how-do-i-play-avi-and-srt-files-together-5886/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a movie container to hold the subtitles and movie there's an answer about that here: [How to soft code an MKV with subtitles?](https://superuser.com/questions/64741/how-to-soft-code-an-mkv-with-subtitles)

If you want subtitles to be forced into the video (they can no longer be turned off), that you can do to an avi with vlc.  Play it with subtitles and re-encode the output.